# How to implement generic dictionary class?

Tags: c#, generics

When I try to run the following code, the **foreach** statement is throwing the below  error at compile time

> Cannot convert type 'string' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair>'

```
namespace myClass
{
public class myDictionary<T>
{
    Dictionary<string, List<T>> dictionary = new Dictionary<string, List<T>>();

    public void Add(string key, T value)
    {
        List<T> list;
        if (this.dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out list))
        {
            list.Add(value);
        }
        else
        {
            list = new List<T>();
            list.Add(value);
            this.dictionary[key] = list;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Keys
    {
        get
        {
            return this.dictionary.Keys;
        }
    }

    public List<T> this[string key]
    {
        get
        {
            List<T> list;
            if (!this.dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out list))
            {
                list = new List<T>();
                this.dictionary[key] = list;
            }
            return list;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return (dictionary as IEnumerable<T>).GetEnumerator();

    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        myDictionary<string> dictionary = new myDictionary<string>();

        dictionary.Add("One", "AA");
        dictionary.Add("One", "BB");
        dictionary.Add("Two", "CC");
        dictionary.Add("Two", "DD");


        foreach(KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> pair in dictionary)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

}

Please let me know what is wrong with my implementation. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your foreach statement expects `MyDictionary<T>` to implement IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, List<T>>`.  So if you want it to work, you will need to implement this, probably by delegating to the private `Dictionary<string, List<T>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    return (dictionary as IEnumerable<T>).GetEnumerator();
}
```

However, you'll need to clarify what this *should* return, since your dictionary is one of lists. Is this meant to be all the values from all the lists in turn? If so, I guess:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    return dictionary.Values.SelectMany(x => x).GetEnumerator();
}
```

If, however, you want to return the pairs, then:

```
public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, List<T>>> GetEnumerator()
{
    return dictionary.GetEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: I need to loop trough the  dictionary and get the all the list values for processing.. Now I am seeing the error: System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,System.Collections.Generic.List<T>>.ValueCollection.Enumerator' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<T>'

Comment: Surely he needs to implement `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, T>>`

Comment: @MarcGravell, Yes I updated my code with your suggestion - return dictionary.Values.SelectMany(x => x); But It didnt work.

Comment: @Ullan then again, it depends on what you're trying do to; what *should* be enumerated? You seem to be implementing `IEnumerable<T>`, but that would make your `foreach` (in `Main`): `foreach(string s in dictionary)`. So: which do you want? I've edited to include examples ofboth

Comment: You probably want to explain why that code is the problem. If the OP didn't know why the code was going wrong in the first place having written it there is a reasonable chance that they may not know what the problem is still, just from being pointed at some code.